# How can I tell if a file will be uploaded to git lfs correctly?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm trying to add everything under `MyProject/Frameworks/` to [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com) (large file storage). I'm [not sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769330/git-lfs-track-folder-recursively#comment95711641_35769868) what the proper format for matching all files and folders recursively under the `Frameworks` folder is. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35769868/35690) says the proper format is `git lfs track "MyProject/Frameworks/**"`, but [Atlassian's help document](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs#tracking-files) says I should use `git lfs track "MyProject/Frameworks/"`. I tried both and they didn't use `git lfs` for storage. It tried uploading files directly.

Sure, I'd love to know the proper format, but more importantly, before I attempt to push my changes to github, I'd like to verify that the match and files do indeed work correctly. This'll allow me to iterate and try new things.

I see two related commands that might help: [`git lfs status`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-status.1.ronn) and [`git lfs ls-files`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-ls-files.1.ronn). It's not clear which one I should be using and what output I should be looking for. For example, when I ran `git lfs status`, it showed me a ton of files under `Git LFS objects to be committed`, making me think they would be added to Git LFS. However, after attempting to push to GitHub.com, I realized that it was clearly not the case. If it helps, the output for these files always had something like `(Git: edee1ad)` after each file name.

When I attempt to use `git lfs ls-files` I'm not sure if I need to run it after `git add`ing the files, after committing them, or after pushing them. Most of the time it's just showing me blank output.

Essentially the question is: **If I configured `git lfs` correctly, what tool (e.g. `git lfs status`) should I use, and what output should I look for *before* I attempt to commit/push?**

**Note:** Please don't answer the question with *only* how to match all recursive files as that will help me once (this specific case), rather than allowing me to iterate and try new things (any case).

Answer (score 149, accepted):

TL;DR

If everything is set up correctly, you can verify that git LFS is going to work properly by:

1. `git add` the file(s) in question.
2. Do one of the following:

   - Run `git lfs status` and ensure the file(s) in question appear under `Git LFS objects to be committed`, and that they have the `LFS` value in parenthesis; or
   - Run `git lfs ls-files` and ensure the file(s) in question appear in this output.

> ⚠️ **Important:** After running `git lfs track`, you must run `git add` to refresh the state of files before calling `git lfs status` or `git lfs ls-files`. Otherwise you'll see irrelevant output from those commands.

Also, for the record, looks like `git lfs track "MyProject/Frameworks/**"` is the correct one for recursive matching.

---

Set up and testing methodology:

1. `git lfs track "*.lfs"`. This generates `.gitattributes`. Leave it unstaged.
2. Create a file in the root directory, `Test.lfs`. Leave it unstaged.
3. Test:

   - `git lfs status`: no filenames output

     ```
     $ git lfs status
     On branch master
     Git LFS objects to be pushed to origin/master:


     Git LFS objects to be committed:


     Git LFS objects not staged for commit:


     $
     ```
   - `git lfs ls-files`: no output

     ```
     $ git lfs ls-files
     $
     ```
4. Add `git add Test.lfs`.
5. Test:

   - `git lfs status`: `Test.lfs` will now be listed with an `LFS` suffix.

     ```
     $ git lfs status
     On branch master
     Git LFS objects to be pushed to origin/master:


     Git LFS objects to be committed:

             Test.lfs (LFS: 2ab9f1e)

     Git LFS objects not staged for commit:


     $
     ```
   - `git lfs ls-files`: `Test.lfs` will now be listed.

     ```
     $ git lfs ls-files
     2ab9f1e447 * Test.lfs
     $
     ```
6. Commit changes.
7. Test:

   - `git lfs status`: `Test.lfs` will move to the "to be pushed" section. It will have a suffix such with a bunch of numbers/letters.

     ```
     $ git lfs status
     On branch master
     Git LFS objects to be pushed to origin/master:

             Test.lfs (2ab9f1e44720efb7a26553e06b667a270320efb3e906553b3f9e0702538a2b3f)

     Git LFS objects to be committed:


     Git LFS objects not staged for commit:


     $
     ```
   - `git lfs ls-files`: `Test.lfs` will continue to be listed.

     ```
     $ git lfs ls-files
     2ab9f1e447 * Test.lfs
     $
     ```
8. Push changes. Including adding/committing/pushing .gitattributes.
9. Test:

   - `git lfs status`: no filenames output anymore

     ```
     $ git lfs status
     On branch master
     Git LFS objects to be pushed to origin/master:


     Git LFS objects to be committed:


     Git LFS objects not staged for commit:


     $
     ```
   - `git lfs ls-files`: Continues to output the tracked file

     ```
     $ git lfs ls-files
     2ab9f1e447 * Test.lfs
     $
     ```

Conclusions:

- The `Git LFS objects not staged for commit` section seems misleading as it never displayed any files, even those that should have been tracked by LFS.
- If you attempt to do the previous experiment with a non git-lfs tracked file, you'll also notice that it appears under the `Git LFS objects to be committed` incorrectly. It is not a Git LFS object. The way you can tell that it's not actually a Git LFS object though is to look at how it ends. If it ends with `(Git: 111111111)` it won't be committed to LFS.
- To avoid the above confusions, you may want to favor `git lfs ls-files` over `git lfs status` to determine if something is going to be part of git-lfs or not.
- Another gotcha: Some applications such as Xcode will `git add` files in a weird way causing what should have been clear matches to not be considered for Git LFS. The solution is to unstage the files and then re-stage them.

Comment: I ran into an edge case where I had added 5 files with the same content (I just copied the files while testing) and they never got sent to LFS.  After committing, they did not show up in the "to push" list returned by `git lfs status`.  I noticed that in `git lfs ls-files` that the files all had the same hash next to them.  If I modify them and present new content, they will be pushed as described above.

Comment: Thanks @PhilGilmore. That's interesting. That sounds like a bug. Did you track to see if they ever fixed this issue?

Comment: @JohnWalker, when I follow these steps I get the line:
Objects to be committed:
        Windows/imagesem (Git: 29c5022 -> LFS: 7b34414)
There is no "Git LFS objects to be committed" but it does include LFS in the brackets. Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: Is it correct that `git lfs ls-files` will list `Test.lfs` already in step 5? For me, this was not the case (and held me up quite a bit because I thought I was doing something wrong).

Comment: Is there a way to check `git lfs ls-files` for a specific file? I have thousands of files and it is a little hard to check if my expected file is added there or not

Comment: Yeah @fuenfundachtzig, same for me in 2023, `git lfs status` lists the file but not `git lfs ls-files`.

Comment: `git lfs ls-files` seems to only show committed files, while `git lfs status` shows staged files.