# Does cherry pick create new files with lfs

Tags: git-lfs, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have a repo with a lot of branches and large files. I need to get a commit from another branch to my branch so I was going to use git cherry-pick but the commit includes a file that is being stored with git lfs.

What I want to know is that will cherry-picking that commit create a new file and store it with git lfs, balloon the size of my lfs storage or will it copy the reference to the old file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54452098